# Refused to frame "vf.force.com/" because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'"

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, content-security-policy

**--- Issue ---**
I have a **LWC** inside my **Managed Package** which dynamically opens a **Visualforce Page** by its name inside `iframe`.

It worked ok in all orgs, However for the last 3-4 months I noticed that if org has:

- **Lightning Web Security** enabled
- **Enable clickjack protection for customer Visualforce pages with headers disabled** - checked ( see it in Setup -> Session Settings ).

than I get next error when opening a **Visualforce Page** inside `iframe`:

> Refused to frame 'https://{domainName}--c.vf.force.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'".

What I see:

[image]

If I disable **Lightning Web Security** or "**Enable clickjack protec...**" it shows me Visualforce Page as expected.

I tried to add next URLs to **CSP Trusted Sites**, however it not helps:

- https://{domainName}.lightning.force.com
- https://{domainName}--c.vf.force.com
- https://{domainName}.my.salesforce.com

**--- Question ---**

Is there **anything I need to add** to my **Visualforce Page** to make it work **without disabling** these Settings ?

Maybe add some **other configurations** in the **Session Settings** ?

*Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, the answer is right there on a **Session Settings** page in **Setup**.
See ***Trusted Domains for Inline Frames*** Section:

> **Visualforce Pages**: Allow iframes of Visualforce pages with clickjack protection on external domains. To enable this feature, add external domains where you allow framing. Then, turn on one of the “Enable clickjack protection for customer Visualforce pages” preferences under Clickjack Protection.

So I added the next **Trusted Domains** there, with **IFrame Type** =   "Visualforce Pages"

- https://{myDomain}.my.salesforce.com
- https://{myDomain}.lightning.force.com

And it now shows me Visualforce Page as expected.

**Useful link:**
[Visualforce page note displaying in iframe: Content Security Policy](https://github.com/developerforce/open-cti-demo-adapter/issues/36)

Comment: Note that if you have enabled the 2 clickjack protection in Session Settings and your User has the 'Development Mode' then you would need to turn off one of them.